# Spring LDAP authenticate method throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

I am trying to use the `LDAPTemplate authenticate` method from Spring LDAP (1.3.1.RELEASE), but it throws following exception

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.authenticate(Ljavax/naming/Name;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z`

Following are my Maven 3.0.1 dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-odm</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-ldif-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-ldif-batch</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Following is the code I used to authenticate

```
    AndFilter andFilter = new AndFilter();
    andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person"));
    andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("uid", "myid"));
    ldapTemplate.authenticate(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, andFilter.toString(), "password");
```

FYI... I have used other `LDAPTemplate` methods like `search`, `bind`, `unbind` without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LdapTemplate.authenticate is quite new.

You probably had an older version of the library cached by Maven (or your IDE), causing the runtime version being older than the one used for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The error went away after restarting the server